# Android Video Recording crashes with Fatal Exception

Tags: android, video, recording

I m trying to add video recording feature in my app but my app is crashing at mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

with following exception :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cameraexample, PID: 26682
java.lang.RuntimeException: set display orientation failed

at android.hardware.Camera.setDisplayOrientation(Native Method)
at com.example.cameraexample.CameraSurfaceView.surfaceChanged(CameraSurfaceView.
java:40)

Any working suggestion ?

Comment: Can you post code what you had tried inorder to solve the exception ASAP